# Why php development server hangs with docker compose?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` configuration file:

```
silex-twig:
  image: php:7.1
  command: php -S localhost:4000 /app/index.php
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - 3000:4000
```

When I run `docker-compose up` it downloads the base image but then it hangs here:

```
Recreating silextwig_silex-twig_1
Attaching to silextwig_silex-twig_1
```

What am I doing wrong? There is nothing available on port 3000.
I know there are setups with php-fpm + nginx but that seemed complicated for only development.

Comment: Does it hang when you are running in daemon mode?

Comment: You can check the logs of the container as well to see what is going on. [more](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/)

Comment: logs are empty, just the attaching message

Comment: How do you know the server in hanging though? Couldn't it be that you are using the container in the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal. It is attaching to the `stdout` of the container (for which there is no `stdout` being logged). At this point, the container is running.

If you want to run in the background you would run with `docker-compose up -d` instead of just `docker-compose up`.

The actual HTTP request to port 3000 won't work because PHP is listening only on localhost. You need to modify your command to be `php -S 0.0.0.0:4000 /app/index.php` so that it is listening on all IP addresses and can accept connections through the Docker NAT.